# Force space between absolute position element and another element

Tags: html, css

I have counter placed in right corner of text area with CSS:

```
   position: absolute;
   @include right(pxToRem(5));
   bottom: pxToRem(45);
   font-family: $font-family-regular;
   color: $text-color-grey-8;
   font-size: $font-size-12;
```

with HTML:

```
<textarea 
placeholder{{translationService.translate('REPORT_ADD_COMMENT')}}"
ngControl="comment" #comment="ngForm"
[attr.maxlength]="maxLengthReportPost"></textarea>
<span class="form__textarea-counter">{{showCharCounter()}}</span>
```

CSS for textarea:

```
min-height: pxToRem(80);
line-height: pxToRem(21);
padding-top: pxToRem(3);
padding-right: pxToRem(13);
```

as result when start typing and close to counter is come very close to counter even under it as
[image]

how I can force spsce between counter and text as
[image]

please without Jquery

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). FWIW, you basically can't with `textarea`. You'd have to create your own textarea widget with regular elements then you'd be able to do something about it.

Answer (score 0):

you might found this helpful, I know this is not 100% full proof but may be it may help you

```css
textarea{
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%; 
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
span{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: -15px;
}
.textarea-holder{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-holder">
  <textarea>
  </textarea>
  <span>11</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I already try to do it, but the problem all lines will far away from the ending eadg, I try to find way to not make text close so much just from the counter
But thank you

Answer (score 0):

Completely changed answer after several comments:

Don't use `position: absolute` for the counter, but make it `display: inline;` and `float left` instead, and erase the `heigth` of the container, and put it into the container as the very last element:

```css
.x1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccf;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
.x2 {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  background: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="x1">asd kja bsd lkj zg kjh iuz kj huz j hjg iuz kjh ku jhg kjh lkj iuz jh kjh iu kj l asd asd asd asd sd asd asd kja bsd lkj zg kjh iuz kj huz j hjg iuz kjh ku jhg kjh lkj iuz jh kjh iu kj l asd kja bsd lkj zg kjh iuz kj huz j hjg iuz kjh kuz j hjg iuz kjh ku jhg kjh lkj iuz jh kjh iu
  <div class="x2">
    counter
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: padding-left not working with position: absolute ... thank you

Comment: yes, it is - look here:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWLXJo (also all other paddings are possible, but in this example I only used padding-left)

Comment: Yes, but this walk around solution not clean one you can not just hide the text under the counter ... but again thank you:)

Comment: You know, your question wasn't really clear, but now I think I understood it, so please take a look at my completely changed answer.

Comment: Hi. I'm already use span tag which by default display as inline
I try this updated solution but still while writing is override the counter ! I;m tired to make it work !!!!

Comment: Yes I am tired too

Comment: Thank you, I take the only option by increase the padding-right for the textarea!!!

Comment: what you mean ?